# Using a concatenated value to find the average

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server 2008 and have concatenated a number of columns to generate a value. However, I want to aggregate the average transaction cost by all unique transactions.

```
Concatenated values = 
SELECT TOP 10 RTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CENTER_NBR AS CHAR)) + CAST(DATEDIFF(ss, '19700101', SALES_DATE) AS CHAR(10)) + 
RTRIM(CAST(REGISTER_NBR AS CHAR)) + RTRIM(CAST(TRANSACTION_NBR AS CHAR)) + CAST(BUSINESS_ENTITY AS CHAR))  AS 'TRANS_KEY'
FROM dh_Transaction_Items;
```

Need to find the following:

```
ROUND(AVG(CAST(ITEM_QTY AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG ITEM QTY', 
ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_PURCHASE_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG PURCHASE AMT',
ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_SAVINGS_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG SAVINGS AMT',
ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_COST_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG COST AMT',
ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_MARGIN_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG MARGIN AMT'
```

Basically, how can I integrate the two sets of sql code to get the averages.

EDIT:

I want to find the average of five columns in the entire table (1+ million rows). The reason for concatenating some of the columns is because that is what the 'desired' unique identifier was. Therefore, the AVG should add the purchase amount for each 'TRANS_KEY' and divide by the total number of values (over 1 million).

Comment: You add them up and divide by 5.  If that isn't what you want, please do a better job of explaining what you really do want.  Sample data and desired results really help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause to get per-group aggregates

```
SELECT
  RTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CENTER_NBR AS CHAR)) + CAST(DATEDIFF(ss, '19700101', SALES_DATE) AS CHAR(10)) + 
RTRIM(CAST(REGISTER_NBR AS CHAR)) + RTRIM(CAST(TRANSACTION_NBR AS CHAR)) + CAST(BUSINESS_ENTITY AS CHAR))  AS 'TRANS_KEY'
 ,ROUND(AVG(CAST(ITEM_QTY AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG ITEM QTY', 
 ,ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_PURCHASE_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG PURCHASE AMT',
 ,ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_SAVINGS_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG SAVINGS AMT',
 ,ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_COST_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG COST AMT',
 ,ROUND(AVG(CAST(EXTENDED_MARGIN_AMT AS FLOAT)), 3) AS 'AVG MARGIN AMT'
FROM dh_Transaction_Items
GROUP BY CENTER_NBR, SALES_DATE, REGISTER_NBR, TRANSACTION_NBR, BUSINESS_ENTITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first select distinct transactions, and then calculate the average values by dividing the sum of qty / amt by the number of unique transactions, as below:

```
WITH distinct_transactions AS
(
    SELECT
    DISTINCT 
RTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CENTER_NBR AS CHAR)) + CAST(DATEDIFF(ss, '19700101', SALES_DATE) AS CHAR(10)) + 
    RTRIM(CAST(REGISTER_NBR AS CHAR)) + RTRIM(CAST(TRANSACTION_NBR AS CHAR)) + CAST(BUSINESS_ENTITY AS CHAR)) AS TRANS_KEY
    CAST(ITEM_QTY AS FLOAT) AS ITEM QTY, 
    CAST(EXTENDED_PURCHASE_AMT AS FLOAT) AS PURCHASE AMT,
    CAST(EXTENDED_SAVINGS_AMT AS FLOAT) AS SAVINGS AMT,
    CAST(EXTENDED_COST_AMT AS FLOAT) AS COST AMT,
    CAST(EXTENDED_MARGIN_AMT AS FLOAT) AS MARGIN AMT
    FROM dh_Transaction_Items
)
SELECT
    ROUND((SUM(ITEM_QTY) / COUNT(TRANS_KEY)), 3) AS AVG_ITEM_QTY,
    ROUND((SUM(PURCHASE_AMT) / COUNT(TRANS_KEY)), 3) AS AVG_PURCHASE AMT,
    ROUND((SUM(SAVINGS_AMT) / COUNT(TRANS_KEY)), 3) AS AVG_SAVINGS AMT,
    ROUND((SUM(COST_AMT) / COUNT(TRANS_KEY)), 3) AS AVG_COST AMT,
    ROUND((SUM(MARGIN_AMT) / COUNT(TRANS_KEY)), 3) AS AVG_MARGIN AMT
FROM distinct_transactions;
```